# Is it possible to use Cloud-Code (inside VSCode) on an RKE cluster?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rke, google-cloud-code

I'm investigating whether it's possible to use cloud-code (inside VSCode) on a private RKE cluster?   Using VSCode, the only options for connecting to clusters seem to involve GCP (or the other large cloud providers) *or* Minikube.   Kubectl is all set up and working great on the cluster - just no support in cloud-code for running/debugging, etc?   Am I out of luck?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to connect an RKE cluster to Cloud Code. If you authenticate against the cluster using the command line, it will create an entry in your `~/.kube/config` that will allow Cloud Code access to your cluster.

(And it can't hurt to double check that the `Default KubeConfig` in Cloud Code's Kubernetes Explorer is pointing to the correct `~/.kube/config` file.)